# clone private repo through php exec

Tags: php, git, ssh, exec, zsh

I'm trying to develop my custom wordpress installer.
To do this i want to clone my templates whoa are in bitbuckets privates repository.

So i got an sh script that is launched by an exec() php command.
In this sh script it try to do something like that :

```
#!/bin/zsh
git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/myTheme.git
```

But the exec() function do nothing, output nothing and return a exit code = 1 
Not very easy to debug.

Do you have any idea of what happen and what can i do to solve it ?
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: check your permissions on the folder. web server needs to have write rights to the directory.

Comment: Check permisisons, try using the full path to git or make sure the environment's path is set properly.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII i'm on a local developpement, it's my user who launch the script (verified with whoami from the shell script).

Answer (score 0):

If your php exec output is empty, maybe you don't see errors, so you have to send yout stderr to stdout

```
exec('git clone <repo_name>  2>&1', $output);
echo implode("<br/>\n", $out);
```